Integrating Active Prospect Trusted Form with Meta Lead ads
I want to integrate active prospect's trusted form with meta lead ads to generate a certificate for every lead I get. Now the certificate generation on trusted form is free and the cost incur on retaining the certificate. And the way to generate a form on a custom website is by adding the trustedForm SDK in the form's HTML. A workaround that can be to create a certificate using an API by active prospect and the data for that lead can be fetched using meta marketing apis. This is a solution which I have come up with but not sure if it is implementable or not.
